# How remove key and value from json file in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonnode

I have the next json file
I want remove key and value for ProductCharacteristic ->name.
How it can be done in Java?

[

{
"id": "0028167072_CO_FIX_INTTV_1008_P3909_IDX0",

"status": "Active",

"startDate": "2023-02-12T22:00:00Z",

"place": [
{

"id": "8",

"apartment": "578",

"role": "QA",

"@referredType": "street"

}
],

"ProductCharacteristic": [
{

"id": "CH_100473",

"valueId": "CH12_1000374_VALUE04141",

"value": "LTS",

"name": "Computer"

}

]
}

]

Comment: how could you normally edit a file in Java

Comment: This question lacks the code with which you load the file. Without that, you won't get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a proper java project set up with Maven, and the following dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20230618</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can parse and edit your JSON as follow:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace with your actual JSON string of load JSON from file
        String jsonString = "{ \"id\": \"0028167072_CO_FIX_INTTV_1008_P3909_IDX0\", \"status\": \"Active\", \"startDate\": \"2023-02-12T22:00:00Z\", \"place\": [ { \"id\": \"8\", \"apartment\": \"578\", \"role\": \"QA\", \"@referredType\": \"street\" } ], \"ProductCharacteristic\": [ { \"id\": \"CH_100473\", \"valueId\": \"CH12_1000374_VALUE04141\", \"value\": \"LTS\", \"name\": \"Computer\" } ] }";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray productCharacteristics = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProductCharacteristic");

        // Iterate through each "ProductCharacteristic" object and remove the "name"
        // key-value pair
        for (int i = 0; i < productCharacteristics.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject productCharacteristic = productCharacteristics.getJSONObject(i);
            productCharacteristic.remove("name");
        }

        String updatedJsonString = jsonObject.toString();
        System.out.println("Modified JSON:\n" + updatedJsonString);
    }
```

Comment: is not work,because my json started with array.I have next error: org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject